I want to install the "n" package and I get an error
After I clean the cache running
npm clean cache --force

I get this warning:

npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.

When I check if the cache is cleaned by running
npm cache verify

I get this error:

npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for n@10.0.0: wanted {"os":"!win32"} (current: {"os":"win32"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid os:  !win32
npm ERR! notsup Actual os: win32
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\SuperElecrtro\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-11-05T14_34_47_325Z-debug-0.log

I found n is written as a bash script. On plain Windows there is no bash shell, so n can not run. What we do is specify in our npm package.json that we do not support Windows, and the error and error message are handled by npm itself. We don't have any control over the message.

This question is similar to: npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for n@2.1.8: wanted {"os":"!win32","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"}). If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

i read article How to update node and npm i want to just update node.js not install angular .

You're trying to install the npm package n? From its docs:

n is supported on macOS, Linux, including with Windows Subsystem for Linux
[...]
n does not work in native shells on Microsoft Windows

That package just won't work on normal Windows. You need to install WSL.
